# Where did the profits for the founders of the Bank of England come from?

Tags: economy

Royal assent was given for the formation of the Bank of England, in part, to help pay for the Nine Years' War (1688-97) with France in 1694. The founding of the Bank and, and in effect, the loan it was created to provide (£1,200,000) were to be financed by subscription payments from 'any person or persons, natives or foreigners, boddies politick or corporate' (p.291). The subscribers were then to be repaid with an annual £100,000 payment which was to be raised from new customs duties and taxes.

The Act of Paliament I just quoted (the Tonnage Act) stipulates that by 1705 (i.e. after 12 years) - with annual payments of £100,000 - the loan would be repaid in full at which time the Bank of England company should 'cease' (p.293) and the loan would, presumably, be considered to have been fully paid. However, the Act also stipulates an 'eight pound per centum per annum' return rate for the subscribers.

My question is: with the twelve £100,000 payments and the subsequent dissolution of the bank there is simply no room for the 8% percent return, so where did it come from?

(All page numbers are from [this book](http://books.google.bg/books?id=0ecuAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA283&lpg=PA283&dq=an%20act%20for%20granting%20to%20their%20majesties%20several%20rates%20and%20duties%20upon%20tunnages%20of%20ships%20and%20vessels%20and%20upon%20beer%20ale%20and%20other%20liquors&source=bl&ots=oploP4mHC_&sig=K2ipNw0Ekx370DWrrnEnbe3f89I&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mhLDUr7fGeeIzAPYpYGADg&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=an%20act%20for%20granting%20to%20their%20majesties%20several%20rates%20and%20duties%20upon%20tunnages%20of%20ships%20and%20vessels%20and%20upon%20beer%20ale%20and%20other%20liquors&f=false) (the link is to Google Books).)

Answer (score 3):

**Section XVIII** of the Act specifies that the amounts you describe are to be kept apart in the accounts of the Exchequer.

This means that the retirement of the principal amount is not being paid annually, as your question assumes, but rather the specified amounts are being paid into what accountants now call a [sinking fund](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinking_fund). , which is paid out in full upon the termination of the Bond.

**Sections XXVII** and **XXVIII** of the Act outlines what investments are, and are not, allowed by the sinking fund.

More information on *sinking funds*, and other means of accounting for liabilities, can be obtained from any Intermediate Accounting course or text book on Liabilities.

**Update** - from my comments below:
Part of the reason for the *sinking fund* is that, provided it is competently managed, the subscribers to the Bond don't **want** to be paid back until the Bond reaches term. The subscribers, by having the accounts and the sinking fund audited, know that the Bond issuer (the Crown in this case) is saving up to repay the Bond.

The terms of **Sections XXVII and XXVIII**, though poorly described in terms of modern accounting and economics, in essence are describing that only low risk investments are suitable for the sinking fund to invest in. In modern terms: No stocks and no junk bonds.

Those *notes* you refer to in your comment are simply *cheques* by another name; financial instruments payable to a named *payee* that can be endorsed to another *payee*. Note the derivation of the (British) English term *cheque*, from *exchequer*.

**Update #2**
For readers who desire more information on this type of accounting, also see [defeasance](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/defeasance.asp). Also, the term *sinking* fund is in no ways meant in a derogatory sense as it is the bond issuer's *liability* that is sinking, or reducing, not the *fund* or other *assets* of the Bond issuer.

**Update #3**:
Referencing *cheque* and *check* in the OED, the former is listed as an alternative spelling for two specific senses of the latter. Usage in this sense is evidenced from 1695 under *check*, and from 1706 under *cheque*, but the spelling in both cases through the 17th and early 18th centuries is *cheque*. The meaning at that time was really for the *counterfoil*, or what we now refer to as the *cheque stub*, rather than for the note or financial instrument itself. *Check* and *exchequer* both derive from the French word for a *checked* cloth, but evolve separately until uniting again in the late 17th century as the newly coined word *cheque*, essentially as a pun on the double derivation.

Rereading portions of the Act again, it seems evident that the subscribers were investing in what we now would call *preferred shares* of the new corporation, not in a *bond*; thus the permanent nature of the loan to the Crown.

Comment: Perhaps it was a typo in your answer, but Section XVIII talks about a single amount (not 'amounts') - the £140,000 that was to be the annual sum of the new taxes imposed by the Act and it states that it should be kept seperately. Presumably, this means apart from other tax revenues.
As to the frequency of payments, Section XXI states that 'the said [...] sums [should be] respectively paid and advanced, as shall be after the rate of eight pounds per centum per annum; and that at any time UPON TWELVE MONTHS NOTICE, after the first day of August' (emphasis mine).

Comment: @absconditus: Yes, it was a typo. Should have read "XXVII and XXVIII", as corrected above.

Comment: XXVII and XXVIII include some of the King's concessions to the subscribers (allowing them to issue notes, for example). Although I do not know what a sinking fund is, I highly doubt the Bank of England was one. In A History of Money, Davies argues that the reason the King consented to having the bank created in the first place was because he could not raise the needed funds to fight France (£1,500,000) all at once from the population. Your argument implies that the (£1,200,000) owed to the subscribers would have had to be paid at once 'upon the termination of the Bond'.

Comment: @absconditus: Read the link for a sinking fund; you are not understanding the accounting involved. I am a (non-practicing) accountant, so I sometimes take more for granted in my explanations of it than I should.

Comment: @absconditus:  Part of the reason for the *sinking fund* is that, provided it is competently managed, the subscribers to the Bond don't **want** to be paid back until the Bond reaches term. The subscribers, by having the accounts and the *sinking fund* audited, know that the Bond issuer (the Crown in this case) is saving up to repay the Bond.

Comment: @absconditus: The terms of **Sections XXVII and XXVIII**, though poorly described in terms of modern accounting and economics, in essence are describing that only *low risk* investments are suitable for the *sinking fund* to invest in. In modern terms: No stocks and no junk bonds.

Comment: @absconditus: Those *notes* you refer to in your comment are simply *cheques* by another name; financial instruments that can be endorsed.

Comment: First I just want to say that I really appreciate all your comments and input. The reason I asked my question in the first place was because I read in Davies' A History of Money that a William Paterson (one of the driving forces behind the creation of the Bank of England) came up with the idea of a "permanent loan" to the government to enable it to finance its war with France and, at the same time, avoid the heavy burden of levying (£1,500,000) on the population all at once.

Comment: [^continued] The government would also have to provide the nascent bank with certain rights that make it - to us - recognizable as such (e.g. issuing notes). At the face of it, it seemed to me that the government had to pay the interest (8% a year) indefenitely (the loan being permanent) - this was what the annual £100,000 were: 8% of £1,200,000 (£96,000) plus a £4,000 servicing fee. Then I thought that no government would simply agree to make perpetual payments on a loan - there had to be a termination date.

Comment: [^continued] Consequently, I went back to the original act and read some of it and found the 1705 termination date which confused me even more. If this was indeed an anachronistic "sinking fund" a termination date, then, and means of levying the necessary funds to settle the loan must have been specified in the act. All the act offers, however, is the 1705 date and the means to pay the annual interest on the loan (the Tonnage Tax).

Comment: There was a difference between cheques and notes back then. According to Davies, "notes" were 'evidence of ability to pay' - i.e. of deposits with the bank/goldsmith, they did not have a payee's name on them. Cheques, on the other hand, were orders to pay a specific sum to a specific person.

PS I have read that "check" was the original spelling in Britain, I could be wrong though.

Comment: @absconditus: Update posted.